# Error: "does not name a type", when a synonym for a type is used when implementing methods outside the class

Tags: c++

Inside the class, I define a synonym for type T* and use it in method signatures. But when implementing methods outside the class, it turns out that the compiler does not understand what `Id` means. Is it possible to fix the error without moving the implementation of the method inside the class?

```
template <typename T>
class PriorityCollection {
public:
  using Id = T*;

  Id Add(T object);

  template <typename ObjInputIt, typename IdOutputIt>
  void Add(ObjInputIt range_begin, ObjInputIt range_end,
           IdOutputIt ids_begin);

  bool IsValid(Id id) const;

  const T& Get(Id id) const;

  void Promote(Id id);

  pair<const T&, int> GetMax() const;

  pair<T, int> PopMax();

private:
  map<size_t, vector<T>> collection;
  map<Id, size_t> ids;
  
  Id Add(T object, size_t priority);
};

template <typename T>
Id PriorityCollection<T>::Add(T object, size_t priority) { // <- error: ‘Id’ does not name a type

    collection[priority].push_back(move(object));
    Id id = &collection[priority].back();
    ids[id] = priority;
    return id;
}
```

Comment: The typename is `PriorityCollection::Id`, not just `Id`

Comment: Show us the full message of the error please

Comment: @UnholySheep even `PriorityCollection<T>::Id` actually.

Comment: The return type is outside of the class scope, so it needs qualifying in the same way as the function name.

Comment: BTW: if you remove all the irrelevant detail (see [mcve]), you can cut this down to `struct A { using T = int; T f(); }; T A::f() { return 0: }`, and probably see what the problem is.